# What's a good discharge current for a LiPo battery without a C rating?

Tags: batteries, lipo

I have a raw (unprotected) 3.7v LiPo cell. It's rated 4000mAh. It has the markings "HRDC 14.8wh 3.7V 606090P 20170528". Apparently 606090 is a number commonly associated with this type of battery, but I can't find a datasheet. What's a safe discharge rate?

Comment: Does “unprotected” mean no current or thermal sensors / control? If it does the 0mA may be sensible....

Comment: @SolarMike Unprotected means all the protection is based on me keeping a close eye on current and voltage with some meters. :)

Comment: Take care with it then .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some data here:

http://www.globalmarket.com/product-info/606090-lithium-polymer-battery-3-7v-400mah-for-smart-watch-10924302.html

strangely the item listed there is not a 606090, but a smaller 592627
but the C ratio will be the same.

this may not be your exact cell but should be representative.

0.5C continuous, 1C peak

Answer (score -1):

You should use a battery that has a current rating "C" that is rated for your load current.
It sounds like you found a battery in a dumpster and are looking for a load for it to drive. If you use it in a Vape'r using a very high current then it might explode in your face or catch on fire.

Some of my RC model airplane Li-PO batteries are rated up to 70C and the weak ones are good for at least 20C.

Comment: You're right about the battery being salvaged, but I don't intend to power any heavy loads with it. I'm using it for a load drawing 2 amps max (0.5C).